# J2EE authentication and In-page bookmarks

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, authentication

I am using J2EE authentication for my application, and mine is single-page web application, which uses '#bookmark' to refresh different sections using Ajax. I wanted to make these links bookmarkable. But the '#bookmark' part is getting removed after authentication.

For example I've a page, which is authenticated, with URL '`http://mydomain/my-page`' and if '`#my-section`' is added to it, page will refresh the section using Ajax, and URL looks like '`http://mydomain/my-page#my-section`'. If I book mark this link, and use it before logging-in, J2EE authentication redirects me to login page, after I provide my credentials, it redirects me to '`http://mydomain/my-page`'.

How can I make it to redirect to the URL with '`#my-section`' part intact?

I can think of a solution using Valve implementation, but is there any other way of doing it?

Using J2EE Form based authentication on Tomcat7, and UserDatabaseRealm as security realm.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you actually implemented the authentication? "JEE authentication" is very non-specific and can mean several things. At the very least there is a part in this process which is server container specific, so please also detail which server you're using and which configuration you did.

Comment: I am using J2EE Form based authentication, Tomcat7, and UserDatabaseRealm for security realm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading, I understood that URL hash is never sent to server, and it is not possible automatically.
we might've to implement solution to store the URL hash locally, and use it to add the same to the URL after successful login redirection.